# hadoop map process error : percent descend to 0 , map completes became nagative number

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Strange that my job looks like this :

The percent of map descends to 0.

```
13/02/15 06:04:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 20% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:14:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 19% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:22:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 18% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:30:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:40:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 20%
13/02/15 06:57:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:06:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:16:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:24:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:33:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:42:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:50:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 20%
13/02/15 07:59:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 7% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:08:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 6% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:16:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 5% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:25:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 4% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:34:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 3% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:42:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 2% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:51:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 20%
13/02/15 08:59:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 20%
```

And the Maps Completed is -4169

```
Jobid   Priority    User    Name    Map % Complete  Map Total   **Maps Completed**  Reduce % Complete   Reduce Total    Reduces Completed   Job Scheduling Information  Diagnostic Info
job_201302111406_2339   NORMAL  hadoop  MonitorUVFreqStatMRPrepare  0.00%
34140   **-4169**   20.92%
60   0  NA  NA
```

Can anybody know what happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a decrease in percentage represents failing of map/reduce tasks after they have been executed for some-time (and hence have a positive percentage). In your case perhaps all the mappers failed making it's percentage to zero.